# How can i notify the Android user if any change /update in any Website for Android device?

Tags: android, android-studio

i want to send a notification when a website update something. (For Android Device)
Is there any way to send notification to my Application user?

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to send a notification when ever you want. This tool is very easy to init and to use.
[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) is the Doc.